How to resize a view from a specific corner with rotation?
I have tried resizing the view from the bottom right corner only without rotating that view but it is now working properly when I try to resize from the bottom right corner with a rotate angle that time it's not working properly. As I have tried with the following code.
But then that view rotated 45 degrees and tried to resize the view from the bottom right corner that time its y value also changed. If any one has a solution for the same please help.
https://i.sstatic.net/MBsYRTfp.png
// Without rotate - fine

@IBAction func onChangedValue(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let x: Double = 0.0
    let angle = x * Double.pi / 180.0
    
    // Reset the transform to avoid accumulating transformations
    self.parentView.transform = .identity
    
    // Store the old frame and origin
    let oldFrame = self.parentView.frame
    let oldOrigin = self.parentView.frame.origin
    
    // Calculate the difference in size
    let diff = CGFloat(sender.value - previousPoint)
    let newWidth = oldFrame.size.width - diff
    let newHeight = oldFrame.size.height - diff
    
    // Calculate the new origin after resizing
    let newOrigin = CGPoint(x: oldOrigin.x, y: oldOrigin.y)
    
    // Update the frame with the new size and origin
    let newRect = CGRect(origin: newOrigin, size: CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    self.parentView.frame = newRect
    
    // Apply rotation
    self.parentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))
    
    // Update the previous point
    previousPoint = sender.value
}

